# mongodb lookup match-expr as second pipeline step

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm relatively new to mongodb aggregations and I have a tiny problem:

I want to make a join between two collections. The problem is, that the foreign field is placed in an inner array. That means that I have to unwind the array in order to make a proper $match. In my $match, I use an $epxr and an $eq in order to make the join on the unwinded documents (which is intended and therefor not a problem). The $expr is needed to access variables from the orginal collection:

```
[
  ...
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'foreignCollection',
      as: 'field',
      let: {
        localField: '$someComparisonField'
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: '$arr'
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [ '$arr.foreignField', '$$localField' ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

However `field` is always an empty array in my result set. I seriously don't know what I'm doing wrong :D

Can someone help me?

**Edit:**
As requested, some sample data for the two involved collections:

orginalCollection:

```
{
  ...
  someComparisonField: 1
},
{
  ...
  someComparisonField: 2
}
```

foreignCollection:

```
{
  ...
  arr: [
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 1
    },
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 1
    },
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 2
    },
  ]
},
{
  ...
  arr: [
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 1
    },
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 2
    },
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 2
    },
  ]
},
{
  ...
  arr: [
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 2
    },
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 1
    },
    {
      ...
      foreignField: 2
    },
  ]
},
```

**Edit 2:**

I forgot to add a small detail: with $eq in the inner pipeline, I am accessing a fixed index which means that the `foreignField` actually looks like this: `foreignField: [ <value> ]`.

Comment: could you post your sample collection

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet updated :)

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong in the above code. Might be the collection name wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet can you maybe have a look at my answer? I did some further investigation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some investigation, I came to the following conclusion:

*Before reading further, I recommend reading both of my edits to the questions. Especially my 2nd edit.*

It seems like $eq within an $expr simply can't compare a fixed index.

This expression simply doesn't work somehow:

```
{
  $expr: {
    $eq: [ '$arr.foreignField.0': '$$localField' ]
  }
}
```

To work arround this, I created an projection before this stage which extracts the value from the desired fixed index and stores it in a new field. So now the particular stages from the inner pipeline look like this:

```
...
{
  $project: {
    value: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$arr.foreignField', 0 ] }
  }
},
{ 
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $eq: [ '$value', '$$localField' ]
    }
  }
}
...
```

Comment: that one works but is extremly slow as `$expr` does not use multi key indexes :(